# How can I create a union type out of array of values?

Tags: flowtype

`$Keys` and `$Values` are useful, but they don't help if I want to create this kind of union type:

```
type Screen = 'screen1' | 'screen2' | 'screen3';

const transitions = [
  {name: 'from1to2', from: 'screen1', to: 'screen2'},
  {name: 'from2to3', from: 'screen2', to: 'screen3'},
  {name: 'from3to2', from: 'screen3', to: 'screen2'},
  {name: 'from2to1', from: 'screen2', to: 'screen1'},
];

// DRY here! But how?
type Transition = 'from1to2' | 'from2to3' | 'from3to2' | 'from2to1';
```

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the best solution so far is a workaround like this:

```
type Screen = 'screen1' | 'screen2' | 'screen3';

const transitionsConfig = {
  from1to2: {from: 'screen1', to: 'screen2'},
  from2to3: {from: 'screen2', to: 'screen3'},
  from3to2: {from: 'screen3', to: 'screen2'},
  from2to1: {from: 'screen2', to: 'screen1'},
};

const transitions = Object.keys(transitionsConfig).map(k => ({
  name: k,
  ...transitionsConfig[k],
}));

type Transition = $Keys<typeof transitionsConfig>;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do this. The values in your `transitions` array are runtime values, while types are a compile-time abstraction. In other words the compiler can't look inside your array because it essentially doesn't exist (or at least, doesn't exist as a thing with a value yet). You probably will have to define your transition types individually and create a union type between them.

Cool idea though. :)